# Azure DevOps Picklist howto know which ID is for what picklist?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When I GET the picklist by id using the REST api, it returns a json like this.

```
{
"items": [
    "Orange",
    "Blue"
],
"id": "65a8a40d-6c22-45ce-af0a-bdfdfdfd335",
"name": "picklist_aef2c045-0d2d-4f92-kjdf-56eea553e1ef",
"type": "String",
"isSuggested": false,
"url": "https://dev.azure.com/organization/_apis/work/processes/lists/65a8a40d-6c22-45ce-af0a-bdfdfdfd335"
}
```

My current aim is to make a script that updates the items within a picklist, but in order to update, I need to know the id of that picklist. All I know from azure devops is the label of the picklist. Is there a way to get the corresponding id with the label? Or is there an alternative? Even if I get the entire list of all picklists within the collection, it still doesn't tell me which is associated to which label so it's not usable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the corresponding id with the label? Or is there an alternative?

The essence of Picklist is the work item field.

You could get the target PickList id with the Rest API: [Fields - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) or [Fields - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

The custom picklist field name: `custom.fieldname`.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I got it working with your solution.